# Microsoft.Web.Identity nuget >=1.9.2 breaks AppService/Azure AD login with 401 response

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-identity-platform, microsoft-identity-web

Testing with a plain vanilla (out of the box sample asp.net 5 MVC web app from VS2019), hosted on an Azure app service (backed with a linux app service plan). Nothing changed or added, except adding an [Authorize] tag to test against a single view from the default controller.

Default App Service in Azure, with a default app registration in Azure AD.

I've noticed every version of Microsoft.Web.Identity >=1.9.2 will break when running in the app service (but works fine locally).  When attempting to reach the protected view, it will return a 401.  Downgrading to 1.9.1 will redirect me to a login page.  Is there some additional configuration that I am missing?

my appsettings configuration

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain.org",
    "TenantId": "XXX",
    "ClientId": "XXX",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-oidc"
  },
```

my startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddRazorPages()
                 .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: You described that I cannot reproduce your problem here. I suggest you raise a support ticket on portal, and let MSFT help you check logs.

Comment: Did you find any fix for this? I'm getting exactly the same issue as you.